# Corba NamingContextExtStub.resolve

Tags: java, corba

first time asking a question here, apologies if its too stupid or simple. I'm learning CORBA and i am writing a simple client server app using object and context bindings but i am getting this error when trying to resolve an object binding, can anyone give me any idea what i am doing wrong?:

```
Bienvenu dans le systeme
Erreur : org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFoundHelper.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.omg.CosNaming._NamingContextExtStub.resolve_str(Unknown Source)
    at CorbaClient.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Client Code

```
package CorbaClient;



import BoutiqueInformatique.*;
import org.omg.CosNaming.*; // inclure le service de nommage
import org.omg.CORBA.*; // manipuler des objets CORBA

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            // creer et initialiser l'ORB
            ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);
            // obtenir une reference au service de nommage
            org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb
                    .resolve_initial_references("NameService");
            // Utiliser NamingContextExt au lieu de NamingContext.
            // car interoperable
            NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);

            System.out.println("Bienvenu dans le systeme");

            // demander la reference de l'objet au service de noms          
            String nom = "Boutique";
            Boutique maBoutique = BoutiqueHelper.narrow(ncRef.resolve_str(nom));



            System.out.println(maBoutique.afficherListeEmploie());

            Emploie monEmploie = maBoutique.creerEmploie("Technicien", 5);
            maBoutique.creerEmploie("Caissier", 2);

            System.out.println(maBoutique.afficherListeEmploie());

            maBoutique.rechercherEmploie("Caissier");

            maBoutique.supprimerEmploie("Caissier");
            System.out.println("Suppression d'un emploie ...");


            monEmploie.ajout(5);
            monEmploie.suppresion(2);


            //Affichage de la moyenne
            monEmploie.moyenneAjout(2);

            //Affichage de l'ecart type
            monEmploie.moyenneSuppresion(2);




        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erreur : " + e);
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    } // fin du main

}
```

Code Serveur

```
package CorbaServeur;

import org.omg.CORBA.ORB;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NameComponent;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExt;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExtHelper;
import org.omg.PortableServer.POA;
import org.omg.PortableServer.POAHelper;

import BoutiqueInformatique.Boutique;
import BoutiqueInformatique.BoutiqueHelper;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            // creer et initialiser l'ORB qui integre
                        // le service de noms
                        ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);
                        // obtenir la reference de rootpoa &            
                        POA rootpoa = POAHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
                        // activer le POAManager
                        rootpoa.the_POAManager().activate();

                        // creer le servant
                        ServeurBoutique BoutiqueRef = new ServeurBoutique("LDLC");

                        // obtenir la reference CORBA du servant
                        org.omg.CORBA.Object ref = rootpoa.servant_to_reference(BoutiqueRef);

                        Boutique href = BoutiqueHelper.narrow(ref);

                        // obtenir la reference du contexte de nommage
                        org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb
                                .resolve_initial_references("NameService");

                        // Utiliser NamingContextExt qui est Interoperable
                        NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);

                        // enregistrer le servant dans le service de nommage
                        String name = "Boutique";
                        NameComponent path[] = ncRef.to_name(name);
                        ncRef.rebind(path, href);

                        System.out.println("Boutique est prÃªte et est en attente.");
                        // attendre les invocations des clients




        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erreur : " + e);
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    } // fin du main
}
```

Comment: Are server and client running on the same host? 
What command line options are you passing?
Do you see the server printing the ready message?  (Questions from Wernke ...)

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that your server terminates before the client can connect. On the server the ORB.run() method must be called in order to listen for incoming client calls.  You may try to call ORB.run() in your main method at the point where your comment correctly states that you have to wait for client calls. Later you might want to move that call into an own thread, especially if your application has a UI to serve.

Comment: There are not that many Corba specialists around any more. I was not allowed to comment, so I tried to be helpful in an answer. But who cares... :(